# Making Oracle sorting case-insensitive?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, nls-sort, nls-comp

This is related to making oracle sorting case-insensitive. Most of the solutions I have seen mentions setting below session params :

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI;
```

By default NLS_COMP is BINARY.

I found that if I just set NLS_SORT to BINARY_CI without setting the NLS_COMP to LINGUISTIC, it still works, i.e oracle sort becomes case-insensitive. Is there any advantage to setting NLS_COMP param ?

Comment: if I want a case in-sensitive search, I use the upper or lower function on the search field...say where UPPER(text) like '%SEARCH_STRING%'

Comment: unless you have hundreds of queries that require case-insensitive sorting, I'd just sort by lower(field) or nlssort(field,'nls_sort=binary_ci'). otherwise, you're trading safety for code simplicity - most of the time nls-dependent code is an accident waiting to happen. in a couple of years some new maintainer, or a new piece of software will set its own session parameters and your queries will just silently fail.

Comment: We do have lots of queries that require case insensitive sorting..Our requirement is that if we are sorting by strings it has to be case-insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT` have slightly different effects. `NLS_COMP` is, as the name implies, for comparisons. `NLS_SORT` is, as the name implies, for sorting. Setting `NLS_COMP` to `LINGUISTIC` causes comparisons to follow the sorting rules, causes comparisons to use the `NLS_SORT` setting. You can see the difference when you try:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 'A' = 'a';
```

With `NLS_COMP = BINARY`, the comparison gives false. With `NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC` and `NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI`, the comparison gives true.

Whether you should set that depends on what results you want to get from your queries.

Comment: Good point. Most documentation I have read does not make this distinction..Lead me to believe case insensitive sorting requires both params to be set